# Creating a menu to switch languages on site

Tags: php, javascript, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu on my site that I want to use to switch between the different languages:

```
 <select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0) self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" name="userLanguage" id="userLanguage">
    <option value="http://demo.com/?lang=en">
                English (International)</option>    
        <option value="http://demo.com/?lang=es">
                Español (European)</option>
                     </select>
```

How can I get the above menu to display which language is currently showing. Is there someway of showing an active state. Site is using php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP this, is a go. (I changed the selection a bit.)

```
<select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0) self.location='http://demo.com/?lang='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" name="userLanguage" id="userLanguage">
    <option <?php if ($_GET['lang'] == "en") { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="en">English (International)</option>    
    <option <?php if ($_GET['lang'] == "es") { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="es">Español (European)</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 If it´s the only field in the form, you can also change the name of the select to `lang` and just submit it.

Answer (score 1):

Add selected="selected" to your option. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/tW2jm/

```
<option selected="selected" value="http://demo.com/?lang=en">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Translate Tools... will save you a whole lot of work in the long run.

http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP I'll suggest you to refector the code like this, because that way you can easily add new language, without writing HTML code or additional javascript. You can use the **$langs** array to hold your current set of languages.

I also made **$server_location** variable that contains the current page URL. That way you will not have problems when you move you page to different servers and domains or if you rename your page.

```
    <?  
        $langs = array('en' => 'English (International)',
                       'es' => 'Español (European)'
                      );

        function is_current_language($code)
        { 
                 return ($code == $_GET['lang'])? 'selected="selected"': "";
        }

        $server_location= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

    ?>

    <select onchange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0) self.location='<?=$server_location;?>?lang='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" name="userLanguage" id="userLanguage">

       <? foreach($langs as $code => $lang): ?>
          <option <?= is_current_language($code); ?> value="<?= $code; ?>">
             <?= $lang; ?>
          </option>
       <? endforeach; ?>

    </select>
```